# Every second Keras epoch returns zero in all logs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, image-classification

I'm attempting to build a simple binary image classifier using Keras and Python. Every second epoch of training returns zero for accuracy, loss, val_accuracy, and val_loss. The other epochs run fine and training progresses normally. I'm training on 25000 unique images, with three sets of convolutions and pooling. I have a 90-10 split for training/testing images and all images are shuffled. I'm currently using the Adam optimizer and an normalized ImageDataGenerator for my labels and data.

## **Here's the error:**

```
Epoch 1/20
90/90 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 170s 2s/step - accuracy: 0.9974 - loss: 0.4769 - val_accuracy: 0.7968 - val_loss: 0.9699
Epoch 2/20
90/90 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 0s 1ms/step - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/20
90/90 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 175s 2s/step - accuracy: 0.9988 - loss: 0.4260 - val_accuracy: 0.8052 - val_loss: 0.9283
Epoch 4/20
90/90 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 0s 728us/step - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00
etc...
```

## **Here's my model structure:**

```
model1 = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Conv2D(16,(3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(150, 150, 3)),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3), activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3), activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])
model1.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0002), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

train_CD = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255.)
train_generator_CD = train_CD.flow_from_directory(
    './images/cat_dog/train_data/',
    target_size = (150, 150),
    batch_size = 250,
    class_mode = 'binary')

test_CD = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255.)
test_generator_CD = test_CD.flow_from_directory(
    './images/cat_dog/test_data/',
    target_size = (150, 150),
    batch_size = 250,
    class_mode = 'binary')

history1=model1.fit(
    train_generator_CD,
    validation_data = test_generator_CD,
    epochs = 20,
    steps_per_epoch = 90,
    validation_steps = 10,
    callbacks=[myCallback()]
    )
```

Comment: You can see that those epochs weren't carried out, as the processing time is `0s` (first number in the log line) in both cases. `batch_size = 250` - This is very unusual, that number should be a power of 2. Can you try, for example, `128`?

Comment: Another observation - you are not showing the call to the `fit()` method (which might be `fit_generator()` - which is deprecated, btw) - are you passing the number of `steps per epoch` for both generators?

Comment: @stateMachine Yeah, not sure why every second epoch would be skipped and the others carried out fine though. I'm using batch_size = 250 because it divides my data length nicely, 22500 / 250 = 90 steps and 2500 / 250 = 10 steps.

Comment: What does `myCallback()` do?

Comment: @NickODell It cancels training once 99.5% accuracy is reached.